# script code to count "spaces" between lines in excel

Tags: excel, ssis

I'm trying to create a SSIS Package to pull all data from an excel source but this source have items and subitems with total and simple values.

My problem is how can i know when an item is parent from another item?

I tried to count "spaces" between two lines and with that to list all items and subitems. But apparently there is no space or tab in this lines (Example below).

[image: Table example in Excel]

The question is: How can I count this spaces between the lines?

Comment: Maybe it's not really spaces but indentation? Try `ActiveCell.IndentLevel` in VBA.

Comment: @JustynaMK This is exactly what i looking for! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped.

Comment: @JustynaMK can you post your comment as an answer, since it resolved the issue?

Comment: Thanks @Cyril, just added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is not not really spaces but indentation. Try using `ActiveCell.IndentLevel` in VBA. See [Range.IndentLevel property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.indentlevel) for more info.

[image]

Comment: I would not be happy at all if this was my source. One more way Excel sources are bad. This is obviously touched/created by a human that will eventually lead to an error.

Comment: Exactly @KeithL in this project that i worked are more than 3 different ways of indent level in the same excel. And i don't know why the local of this project don't make one equal process for everything!